# Problema com os parâmetros passados para PHPlot pelo Controller do Codeigniter

Tags: codeigniter, construtor, php

Estou com uma dúvida que ao mesmo tempo esta sendo um problema, pois não sei o que posso estar fazendo de errado.

É o seguinte, estou usando o Codeigniter e para gerar um gráfico vou usar a biblioteca [PHPlot](http://www.phplot.com/), o básico eu consegui gerar o gráfico necessário, o problema começou quando precisei alterar o tamanho da imagem gerada, que nessa biblioteca é passado pelo `__construct` da classe.

Para isso movi a biblioteca para pasta `thirdy_party`, dai na pasta libraries criei uma classe chamada `CIPHPlot` extendendo a biblioteca, dai com isso o controller e essa minha classe `CIPHPLot` ficaram assim:

```
class Welcome extends CI_Controller {

    public function Index(){
        // Carregamos a library PHPlot
        $this->load->library('CIPHPlot', array(1200, 800));
```

e a library CIPHPLot assim:

```
<?php if (!defined('BASEPATH')) exit('No direct script access allowed');

require_once APPPATH."third_party/PHPlot.php";

class CIPHPlot extends PHPlot {

    public function __construct($params = array())
    {
        $width       = 600;
        $height      = 400;
        $output_file = NULL;
        $input_file  = NULL;

        if(isset($params) && is_array($params)) {
            if (isset($params[0])) {
                $width = (int) $params[0];
            }
            if (isset($params[1])) {
                $height = (int) $params[1];
            }
            if (isset($params[2])) {
                $output_file = $params[2];
            }
            if (isset($params[3])) {
                $input_file = $params[3];
            }
        }

        new PHPlot($width, $height, $output_file, $input_file);

        parent::__construct();
    }

}
```

Até aqui aparentemente tudo certo, pois agora se eu for dentro do construct da biblioteca PHPlot e der um `var_dump` no primeiro parametro, no caso o `$width` ele irá exibir o valor passado no Controller, no caso 1200, mas quando gera o gráfico, ele gera com o tamanho padrão de 600 e não com o de 1200 como é impresso no `var_dump`.

```
class PHPlot
{

    function __construct($width=600, $height=400, $output_file=NULL, $input_file=NULL)
    {
        var_dump($width);die();
        $this->initialize('imagecreate', $width, $height, $output_file, $input_file);
    }
```